# Trying to get a while loop to alert/log a string 3 times but instead it only logs once

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

The tutorial I'm following says that I need to use a while loop to log to the console "I'm looping!" three times without actually calling the console.log command three times.  This is what I have, however when I run it, it only logs the string once and if I call my loop function 5 or more times, then it doesn't log at all.

```
var count = 0;

var loop = function(count){
    while(count < 4){
        console.log("I'm looping!");
        count++
    }
};

loop(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `count` argument you've declared in your function shadows the `count` variable outside the function. ("Shadows" = "hides", e.g., the argument makes the variable inaccessible by name.) Since you're passing in the value `3` for the argument, the loop only runs once, as `3 < 4` but then you incremented it and `4 < 4` is false.

If you want to use the `count` variable declared outside the function, change the name of your argument and/or don't provide one at all:

```
var count = 0;

var loop = function(){
    while(count < 4){
        console.log("I'm looping!");
        count++
    }
};

loop();
```

The **first** time you call `loop`, it will loop *four* times (once for `0`, for `1`, for `2`, and for `3`). Any subsequent calls won't loop at all (unless you change `count`).

If you want to loop **up to** a given number of times, but never let `count` be `>= 4`, use a different name for the argument:

```
var count = 0;

var loop = function(c){
    var i = 0;
    while(count < 4 && i < c){
        console.log("I'm looping!");
        count++;
        ++i;
    }
};

loop(3);
```

The first time you call that, it will loop three times, once for `0`, then for `1`, then for `2`. Then, `i` is `== c` and so the loop does not continue. If you called `loop` again, it would run up to one time, at which point `count` would be `4` and the loop body would never be run.

Comment: @T.J. - Thanks for your quick response.  That makes sense.  I also played around with the script some more and realized that I can get rid of the global var and just do loop(1) and I get the console to log it 3 times.